# How can I run a !<cmd> from a vim script when the path has a space in it on Windows?

Tags: vim

I'm attempting to use the `:!<cmd>` format in vim to execute an external command and put the results in the buffer.  If I type `:!`, path completion is possible and I can complete the path right up to the command I want to execute.  This automatically escapes spaces like so:

```
:!c:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 9.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe
```

When I hit enter, I get:

```
'c:\Program\' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Which I suspect means that vim has not escaped the spaces properly when passing the command to cmd.exe.  I've tried all sorts of escaping combinations to make this work but to no avail.  The only way I've found to do this is to work out what the DOS8.3 filename is and use that instead of the long path name.  However, I don't like this approach since it's going to make my script less portable.  Does anyone know if this can be done, or is it a bug in vim?

Comment: can you try doing this `:!c:\Program\ /Files\ /(x86)\Microsoft\ /Visual\ /Studio\ /9.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe`

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to work.. The issue appears to be that cmd.exe doesn't support escaped paths, it only supports quotes.  Just typing cmd.exe /c c:\Program\ Files\test.exe in cmd prompt causes the same issue.

Comment: Does just putting quotes around the path work?

Comment: I was going to say that next @Randy. the issue here is i am a unix/linux kid not windows

Comment: Actually, I've just realised that putting quotes in does work from the vim command line in a live session, although not from my script.  It looks like vim is not treating the quotes as literal in the script and is not passing them on.  I'm sure a bit more fiddling will get there ;-)

Comment: Can you give us some context with your script?  A dummy function or something?

Comment: @Randy, I'm trying to execute tf like so: silent! exe 'r!"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" history /followbranches "#"'

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if the problem lies in the `#` and not in the path. Is this expected to be a literal "#"?

Comment: glad stack was able to help you through this. I learned something.

Comment: @John, possibly a bit premature, I haven't got it working yet ;-)  I'm still fiddling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have quoted arguments, not just the exe path, then you may need to do some fancy quoting, like below.  The main problem is not the exe path itself, but the arguments.  I found this webpage helpful for similar problems myself:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx

Not sure offhand and don't have time to check, but if you have a quoted argument then sample below may be closer to what you need:

```
silent! exe 'r!"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" history /followbranches \^"#\^"'
```

Also, I wonder whether the quotes around the path may need special treatment since they are around only a portion of the full command.  In any case, the quotes `\^"` work for main quotes in command line and `^"` for quotes embedded in other quotes. I have in the past found it useful to experiment with the command at a windows prompt, remembering to test it with the way Vim prepares it, which is with your command prepended by `c:\windows\sys32\cmd.exe` .

On second thought, I think when I was working with similar problem I never did get to point of solving command with both quoted arguments and quoted exe-path-with-spaces in same command.  I expect there's way to do it, but I instead just created a soft link to the exe in path with no spaces. E.g.:

```
 mklink c:\users\myname\myexe c:\program files(x86)\myapp\myexe.exe
```

After having done that there's no need to quote the exe command itself and quoting the argument with `\^"` worked fine.  I am of course curious about how to quote an `exe-with-spaces` that also has quoted arguments.

EDIT: I think I found way around my problem with quoting, don't have VS to test with your exact command but here's what I think may work from command line:

```
cmd /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" history /followbranches ^"#^""
```

If that works for you from command line then I think only issue is getting Vim to include the /k switch.  (Also, there could be issue with Windows command line "throwing away" the /followbranch switch, because of the forward slash, but maybe not.)

EDIT2:  I think the trick for doing it from Vim is just to include the 'cmd /k' as part of the command you're running.  You end up with several levels of shells opening, but I don't think that's a problem.  For an example, here's on that runs from Vim, with (1) spaces in exe path, (2) quoted argument (the `(message .. )` ) and even (3) a quote within a quoted argument (`\^"hi\^"`).  This command opens an Emacs instance and has Emacs print message "hi":

```
!cmd /k ""c:\program files (x86)\emacs\emacs\bin\emacs.exe" --eval ^"(message \^"hi\^")^""
```

And yet one more EDIT:  Including your own 'cmd /k' does create problems, I think, if you're trying not just to execute the external command, but to read its output back into the Vim buffer.  In that case you could redirect the output to a file in the user's home directory and the use `:read` to insert into the buffer.  If there's some way to get Vim's own cmd to use k switch then this would be unnecessary, but if not then at least this provides good workaround.

Comment: Hmm, the first idea with silent exe doesn't appear to work, although I've never seen ^ escaping before so that was interesting.  The second idea with mklink does work but if I'm to give this script to other people, I'm not keen on creating links to no-space paths on their machine.  Thanks though!

Comment: You were quite correct though about "#" it was this parameter that was screwing the command up.  Oddly this worked fine when I was using DOS83 paths because I didn't have to quote the command it's self...  Sigh..

Comment: @Benj -- Yes, the soft link isn't good solution if it needs to be deployed on other users' machines.  I think there must be a way to do it with exe-path-with-spaces but I haven't found it.  Will look for it a little harder now. . .

Comment: @Benj -- Think I found a way to do it, but it requires (I think) use of the `/k` command switch.  Not sure how to get Vim to include that when creating full command for shell.  Example for command line is now up in my post above.

Comment: Hey, this works:  I ended up with: exe '!'.'cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" history /recursive ^"#^""'

Comment: Thanks for your help, here's the finished plugin (with your suggestion in version 1.1.1) http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3808

Comment: I am still curious to know what about the "#" argument was causing the trouble. When the alternate filename was substituted in, what special characters did it contain?

Comment: @MetaEd -- I think problem is on Windows command line and parsing of the double quotes around an argument.  Expansion of the # symbol itself is not an issue.

Comment: @Benj -- Just checked and my own last example in post does also work with a 'cmd /c' prefix instead of 'cmd /k'.  I wonder why that is, since Vim itself puts its own 'cmd /c' prefix on any external command string it runs.  Important thing is that it's working, though.

Comment: @Herbert Sitz Expansion of the `#` symbol must have been relevant. The `^` prefix escapes the special function of the double quotation marks, and double quotation marks simply escape any special function of all characters within the quoted region. The quotation marks are still passed by CMD.EXE to TF.EXE in the command line. If there were no special characters in the expansion of the `#` symbol, the `^` prefix would have made no difference in how the command line was assembled. I imagine there are some CMD shell special characters in the expansion of the # symbol which are creating a problem.

Comment: @MetaEd -- No, the # symbol, as far as I know, is simply expanded into a filename.  The metacharacter for the quotes is needed around quotes for any argument, though, whether the arg is one that gets expanded or not. See, e.g., the command in my post that I need to invoke Emacs with arguments.  This is all explained in the MSDN article linked at beginning of my post.

Comment: @MetaEd - The # is indeed just epanded to the filename, the issue seems to arise when you attempt to quote both the command you're running and any of it's parameters.  This won't work in windows unless you start putting the whole thing in quotes with ^"^" around quoted params.  Nice work Herbert Sitz (and nice work with VimOrganiser too ;-) )

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the full pathname of the executable in double quotation marks. Do not escape spaces in the pathname.

In your example, some of the backslashes were added to escape spaces, and others are a part of the pathname. You did not provide the original pathname, but I can guess at it. If I guessed right, the command that will work is:

```
:!"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"
```

This works equally well in a script. The equivalent script command is:

```
silent execute '!"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"'
```

I have tested this in Vim 7.3.346 x86, installed on Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64.

Comment: This does work as discussed in the comments, any idea how I run it like this from a script.  I've tried: silent! exe 'r!"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" history /followbranches "#"'

Comment: Added a script example. I say I have tested this, but of course I have only tested this with a similar pathname containing spaces, not with your exact pathname, because my software load differs.

Comment: Hmm, did you test both of these commands?  The first works, as discussed.  But the second is what I've already tried and does not work for me.  The quotes appear to be lost by the time the command is passed to cmd.exe.

Comment: Apologies, this command on it's own does work, it's the "#" parameter that's screwing everything up.

Comment: Vim substitutes the alternate file name for the #. So what we would now like to know is what the command line looks like after the substitution. You could, for example, add a debugging line which reads: execute '!echo #'

Answer (score 0):

```
       %0 (batch name) %1 (1st parameter) %2 (2nd parameter)
```

**example:**

> C:\CSW>MyBatchFile.bat "C:\Program files" "C:\CSW\My File.txt"

Not sure if this works with vim but it does work with bash in windows.

Comment: The only problem with this, is that I'd still have to tell vim to execute the batch file.  Since I don't control where the batch file might get put on the end user's system, that could also be in a path with spaces in it.  Which would cause the problem all over again.

Comment: Alright let me think about this. Hopefully someone with a little more experience in this will show up.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call by adding double quote in it.
I dont have enough idea about Vim script. but while running in command prompt if you will give the complete exe path having space then it will give error like

C:>c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

But It will work if you will surrounded with double qoute.

C:>"c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

C:>